# Extract the parent folder of a directory using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

Suppose I have the following folder

```
std::string m("C:\MyFolderA\MyFolderB\MyFolderC");
boost::filesystem::path p(m);
```

Is there anyway for me to extract the parent of this folder. I want to get the string `MyFolderB.` from the above path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is method [parent_path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-parent_path), check the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was very helpful

Comment: Note that the OP wanted to get the name of the "MyFolderB" folder. However, `parent_path()` returns the **full path** to the "MyFolderB" folder, so we may need to use [`boost::filesystem::path.filename()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-filename) to extract the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you prefer a string manipulation method.

```
#include <algorithm>

const std::string m("C:\\MyFolderA\\MyFolderB\\MyFolderC");
const std::string slash("\\");
auto last_slash(std::find_end(std::cbegin(m), 
                              std::cend(m), 
                              std::cbegin(slash),
                              std::cend(slash)));
auto second_to_last_slash(std::find_end(std::cbegin(m), 
                                        last_slash,
                                        std::cbegin(slash), 
                                        std::cend(slash)));

const std::string parent(++second_to_last_slash, last_slash);
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/154ae514bc9ff61c), if you're into that.

Comment: Good point! The user's question used Windows-style paths, so that is how I solved it. I believe this would work with an arbitrary string `m` if `slash` were `#ifdef`ed to be initialized as `"/"` in Linux contexts.